# link triggered by expanding element on iPad

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

For a site I'm working on, I have a bottom bar that expands upwards when you mouseover (desktop) or tap (touch device) on it. However, on touch devices (notably the iPad) tapping on it also triggers the links in the part that is revealed.  Have a look at the test page I've created: 
http://www.ronderksen.nl/experiments/testpage2.html

I can't figure out what is causing this behaviour and I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on it!

Comment: Looking at your sample, you have your script listening to a 'click' or 'tap' event. Did you change something between asking the question and today?

Comment: Well, for one this isn't happening for me on my iPad or my iPhone. Also, you don't have the bar expanding on mouseover, it's happening on click.